# Websockets "multicasting" PHP

Tags: websocket

Me and my friend having a little bit of a problem using websockets, I'll quickly explain so we maybe could get it working.

We got a websocket server up and running and its doing fine, lisening to a specific port and connects all our clients as it should.

But we would like to have channels. For an example: http://www.example.com/channel/682831

And we can't figure out how to solve that, because right now its like "broadcasting" and we would more likely have "multicasting"
where we could say this message is going there and this message is going here.

So please help us.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

WebSocket provides point-to-point raw messaging. What you describe usually runs under the term "Publish & Subscribe".

A subscriber signals it's interest in a topic, publisher send events to that topic, and a broker dispatches events to the right clients based on a book of subscriptions it maintains.

This needs to be layered on top of WebSocket. You might have a look at [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/), an open standard WebSocket based protocol that provides Publish & Subscribe (as well as Remote Procedure Calls).

Disclosure: I am original author of WAMP (now an open community effort) and work for Tavendo.